# New line in PHP output in a text file

Tags: php, forms, text-files, output

My php form which saves the output in a text file glues the result to one string like:

Name1Email1The Message1Name2Email2The Message2Name3Email3The Message3Name4Email4The Message4

But I need spaces and/or newlines. I normaly don't use PHP so I don't get it. I did't find an answer on the web, also read some Q/A here, but this didn't help me.

The Form:

```
<form action="mailer.php?savedata=1" method="post">
Your Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
Your Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
Your Message:<br> <textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The PHP

```
<?php
$savedata = $_REQUEST['savedata'];
if ($savedata == 1){ 
$data = $_POST['name'];
$data .= $_POST['email'];
$data .= $_POST['message'];
$file = "YOURDATAFILE.txt"; 

$fp = fopen($file, "a") or die("Couldn't open $file for writing!");
fwrite($fp, $data) or die("Couldn't write values to file!"); 

fclose($fp); 
echo "Your Form has been Submitted!";

}
?>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As other answers state, you need to add in an end of line character after each field.

Different OS's use different line endings, though, and so a "\n" may not display as a new line on Windows, for example. As Mahdi said, you can use Windows style "\r\n" line endings, or you can use the [PHP_EOL](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) constant so that line endings appropriate to the server will be output, in which case your code would look like

```
$data = $_POST['name'] . PHP_EOL;
$data .= $_POST['email'] . PHP_EOL;
$data .= $_POST['message'] . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Thanks to all! I choose your answer cause the different OS argument.

Answer (score 6):

You can use "\n" to write a new line.

```
$data = $_POST['name'] . "\n";
$data .= $_POST['email'] . "\n";
$data .= $_POST['message'] . "\n";
```

Just as a sidenote, \n has to be in doublequotes. When surrounded by single quotes it won't work.

Comment: 9 years later..this sidenote is still valid. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

When you concatenate your input values like that you won't have any newlines; you can add them using the literal `"\n"` or `"\r\n"`. To string them all together you can use the concatenation operator or use `sprintf()` like below:

```
$data = sprintf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", $_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['messge']);
$file = "YOURDATAFILE.txt"; 
file_put_contents($file, $data, FILE_APPEND);
```

I also use `file_put_contents()` with the `FILE_APPEND` flag to append data to a file and save a few more lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

I usually combine `New Line` with `Carriage Return`:

```
$data = $_POST['name'] . "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the filter that you're using to clean form input.  It may be removing the 0x0a NewLine characters from your form input.

I have text saved from a 'textarea' tag and it's correct.
Using a HEX viewer, I see that each newline from the "textarea" field gets translated to hex character 0a.  (decimal 10)  Wikipedia lists this as the UTF-8 "newline character" or "LF."  LF was short for Line Feed, from the old teletype days.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

So, the lines
test
test
test 
translate to "4 65 73 74 0d 0a 74 65 73 74 0d 0a 74 65 73 74"
Note the two "0a" characters in the string, which are equivalent to \n.

This wasn't apparent at first because the regular expression I was using to clean the input was replacing the 0a character with a space.

Answer (score 0):

you'r `$data` variable needs to already have the `\n` new line characters in it.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
echo "$data"."\r\n";
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

When we attempt to extract data submitted online via a Web-Form and to write the same to a text file which is placed on the web-server -- without overwriting the information already contained in the said text file, then we use the following code within the  tags:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="">
<input value="submit">
<div>Name: <input value=""></div>
<div>email: <input value=""></div>
...           ...         ...
<div><button>Submit</button></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The above HTML Code is coupled with the following PHP Code:

```
<?php
$fileName = 'fdata.txt';
$fp = fopen('fdata.txt', 'a');
 $savestring = $_POST['name'] . ',' . $_POST['email'] ;
fwrite($fp, $savestring);              
fclose($fp);
?>
```

But the above two Codes together lead to data that is appended and stringed together in the text file -- that is to say, every new record (set of data) extracted from subsequent Web-Forms does not begin at a new line (there is no line-break or carriage-return).

I searched the Net for a Solution to the above Issue -- as suggested on the Net, I added “\r\n” (in double quotes) and also used ‘PHP_EOL’ (without quotes) as under:

```
$fp = fopen('fdata.txt', 'a', "\r\n");
$savestring =  “\r\n” . PHP_EOL .  ' ' . $_POST['name'] . ',' . $_POST['email'] . 
PHP_EOL;
```

Yet there was no line-break at all (my web-server and my desktop use Windows). It means that there was no practicable Solution within the knowledge of anyone of the millions of Users of Net in the World. It appears that the parameter ‘a’ overrides “\r\n”, ‘PHP_EOL’ etc.